# How to communicate with several subprocesses simultaneously?

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

I have a script in Python that needs to run multiple subprocesses simultaneously, providing input to all of them and capturing the output. Currently, I have this:

```py
proc1 = subprocess.Popen(
    'proc1',
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    text=True
)
proc2 = subprocess.Popen(
    'proc1',
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    text=True
)
proc1_output = proc1.communicate(input1)
proc2_output = proc2.communicate(input2)
```

The problem is `proc1` and `proc2` interact with each other, but need their input to do so. So [`communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) won't actually work for this since it doesn't return until the process exits.

One solution I've seen suggested is to use the `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` file descriptors on `proc1` and `proc2` directly:

```py
proc1.stdin.write(input1)
proc2.stdin.write(input2)
output1 = proc1.stdout.read()
error1 = proc1.stderr.read()
output2 = proc2.stdout.read()
error2 = proc2.stderr.read()
```

This isn't a good solution because it [creates the possibility of deadlock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdin) if, say, the stderr buffer fills while trying to `read()` stdout. Or if the stdin buffer fills for `proc1`, which stops reading it while waiting for the first response from `proc2` (not sure if that one is actually possible, but it seems plausible).

Is there a way to safely provide input and read the output of multiple subprocesses running simultaneously?

Comment: On a Unix-like system (e.g. Linux), you can use `select` to know whether next read or write could block.

Comment: @SergeBallesta That doesn't provide any guarantees though, does it? E.g. if the input is big enough, `.stdin.write()` could still block? And for that matter, `.read()` doesn't seem to have any way to quit early if only some data is available

Comment: No. The goal of `select` is precisely to identify which IO connection is ready for read of write. If select says that you can read or write, it guarantees that the read of write will not block. If may return (or write) less bytes than expected, but it will return immediately.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I believe that is true for subclasses of [`RawIOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase), but not in the general case. See for example [`BufferedIOBase.read()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase.read), which will happily attempt multiple `read()`s, blocking if necessary, until it has the requested number of bytes ([simple test script using a FIFO](https://gist.github.com/dominickpastore/db7d07c87188ada69430b383fdc4e253)). I haven't tested `write()` but I assume the results are similar.

Comment: You could try to communicate using different threads or possibly using `async` functionality (if the `read`/`write` functions allow for other parts to run when they block).